# Django how to tell if signal was called in a request or not

Tags: python, django, celery, signals

I'm using Django 1.10.

Is there a way to tell in a signal whether the `save()` that triggered that signal was called within the view `Request` or by a 'manual' `save()`?

I have a signal that does some action. I want to do a different action, depending if I'm in a middle of a request or not (updating objects in a Celery task).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't. At least not out of the box.

Longer answer: you could solve this using some threadlocal hack -  cf [this project for example](https://github.com/benrobster/django-threadlocals) - but please carefully read the caveats.

Or you could just use something else than orm's pre/post save signals to trigger your actions - for example [sending your own signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/#defining-and-sending-signals) from where it makes sense. As far as I'm concerned that how I'd first try to solve the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at Django Documentation,
But as far as I know, you should define your model inside /urproj/urapp/models.py, which are normally a class statement. and using the route method inside /urproj/url.py whcih also can be inside your app as well.  I have this approach to detect whether a Get request is healthy or not, for instance?!

```
class Expense(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    amount = models.BigIntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

def __unicode__(self):
    return "{}-{}-{}".format(self.date, self.user, self.amount)
```

then I use routing method like this?

```
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
              url(r'^submit/expense/?$', views.submit_expense, name='submit_expense'),
              ]
```

I hope I have had answered your question!

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really the question.

Comment: Actually it really has nothing to do with the question - and your code example is broken...